# I am using JPA and hibernate for my project. Sometimes it works great. Sometimes getting internal server error

Tags: hibernate

I am using hibernate in my project. Using eager fetch. If I use Lazy fetch getting error. But eager fetch  getting internal server sometimes. How to handle this?

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="healthHomeService",cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER,orphanRemoval=true)
```

Comment: Can you add error log?

Answer (score 0):

In error log when this internal server error happens , I dont see any error messages. This happens when trying to save a transaction or find a recipient.

But Other errors I gor from sys.out

4/10/19 15:17:05:744 EDT] 000004f6 SqlExceptionH Z org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions SQL Error: -911, SQLState: 40001
[4/10/19 15:17:05:760 EDT] 000004f6 SqlExceptionH Z org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions The current transaction has been rolled back because of a deadlock or timeout.  Reason code "2".. SQLCODE=-911, SQLSTATE=40001, DRIVER=4.19.77
[4/10/19 15:17:05:760 EDT] 000004f6 AbstractBatch Z org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl release HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements

com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: [jcc][10120][10943][4.19.77] Invalid operation: statement is closed. ERRORCODE=-4470, SQLSTATE=null

For errorcode 4470, I set the alllowExhaustedresultset=yes in websphere.

But still it does not fix completely.

Answer (score 0):

RC = "-911" in DB2 means a deadlock occurred. This is intermittent because of the nature of the concurrent threads trying to update the same resource in DB2

From the DB2 manual: SQL0911N   [The current transaction has been rolled back because of a deadlock or timeout. Reason code reason-code](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc-gentopic2.html#sql0911n)

It seems you business logic makes updates on your database on the same resource that cause deadlocks
Change the code in a way it does not cause  [deadlocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) or change the isolation level to avoid such situations or change the way you map the relationship in JPA to avoid the updates